# How to add a directory to Eclipse build path from an plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I try to create an eclipse plugin which will provide a new "New Project" wizard which should create new project based on an template pom.xml.

Asking data from the user as well as creating the project in the workspace works fine. However, I'm not able to tell eclipse from the plugin, that the directories I created ('src/main/java' and co) should be used as src directory.
I tried to use the IWorkspace and IFolder types, but they don't seam to have the necessary functionality.

Does anybody has experience with this, and/or has an link to the appropriate place in the eclipse documentation? (I've tried to find something, but its hard not to get redirected to actual plugins or questions for plugin users...)

Comment: Why not just use the Maven integration plug-ins from http://eclipse.org/m2e/?

Comment: I'd like to have a wizard, where the developer just needs to insert the project name and description and the rest is created automatically. This includes pom.xml with dependecies, stub classes, configuration files etc. which are tailored to our build environment. Didn't found something, which allows me to do this.

Comment: The core Eclipse code such as `IWorkspace` does not know anything about Java. You will have to look at the Eclipse JDT plugins. It looks like `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIClasspathEntry.html) of `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry` looks good but I think I need also to enable the project nature first. I will write an answer to this, after I've tried it.